# Joomla and Movable Type API

Tags: live, xml-rpc, joomla1.5, writer

I am running XAMPP locally with Joomla 1.5.22 installed. I wanted to enable front end user to just use MS Windows Live Writer so I have installed  XML-RPC - MovableType API did enable Web Services. In the MS Windows Live Writer for my joomla website I input localhost/joomla or 10.1.1.106/joomla with my back end admin credentials. After that I choose Movable Type API which asks for remote posting web address for my blog for which I try to input localhost/joomla/xmlrpc/index.php and I get an error: "Can't connect to your blog service: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. Please fix and try again."

Can any one suggest anything that could help me to resolve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one tried to solve this I had to come up with a solution which did work at the end but now I'm having other problems (I'll get back to that in few). I have my Blog Service as Movable Type API, the web address http://localhost/joomla with localhost/joomla/xmlrpc/index.php for my Remote Posting web address for my blog. It's working now. Yay